# How this animation work?

Tags: javascript, animation, frontend

Here is example: https://beta.virusbay.io/
As you can see, on the background there are many moving points. Is it some kind of animation in file or this work with JS? How to do smth like this on your own site?

Comment: Please include relevant code in the question and don't point us to a questionable URL. I'm hesitant to head anywhere near a site called "virusbay". Furthermore, at StackOverflow, it is expected you put some effort into solving your problem. Take the [tour] and read the [help] to get a better idea on how to ask a good question. Don't just point to a location the web then ask "How do I do that?"

Comment: Sorry, i can not find the code there so i have just an example of site which used that feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This uses particle.js - https://vincentgarreau.com/particles.js/ An Open source library.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i am looking for!